# Почему веб шрифт из иконок не отображается?

Tags: html, css, шрифты, icon, web-fonts

Я создал свой веб-шрифт из svg иконок через iconmoon. По гайдам все подключил, однако ничего не отображается. В первом варианте я подключал стили с шрифтами через link в html, во втором случае добавил CSS из шрифтового файла в свой основной. Ничего абсолютно не отображается, даже пустой символ. Элемент точно видимый, т.е. не перекрывается и не сливается с фоном.

```
<span class="icon icon-Graph">&#xe802</span>
```

вот пример использования иконки из "коробки". С тегом i тоже пробовал. Ни код символа, ни сам тег(даже пустой) не превращаются в иконку. При всем при этом demo-html который идет в комплекте со шрифтом от самого сайта прекрасно работает и отображает все иконки и через тег с классами и через код. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие могут быть причины происходящего?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так подключается у меня, формируется icomoon на сайте - https://icomoon.io/app/ 
Вполне возможно вы просто путь не правильно прописали до файлов icomoon.
Также посмотрите повнимательней, возможно на вашем сайте написаны стили, которые делают иконки невидимыми - например height может быть равна нулю или font-size: 0;

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('../font/icomoon.eot?mjz2xk');
  src:  url('../font/icomoon.eot?mjz2xk#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../font/icomoon.ttf?mjz2xk') format('truetype'),
  url('../font/icomoon.woff?mjz2xk') format('woff'),
  url('../font/icomoon.svg?mjz2xk#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: never;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-chevron-double-left:before {
  content: "\e915";
}
.icon-chevron-double-right:before {
  content: "\e916";
}
.icon-clipboard-export:before {
  content: "\e914";
}
.icon-avatar-empty:before {
  content: "\e913";
}
.icon-check:before {
  content: "\e90e";
}
.icon-calling:before {
  content: "\e904";
}
.icon-eye-hide:before {
  content: "\e907";
}
.icon-eye-light:before {
  content: "\e908";
}
.icon-address:before {
  content: "\e900";
}
.icon-briefcase:before {
  content: "\e901";
}
.icon-building:before {
  content: "\e902";
}
.icon-calendar:before {
  content: "\e903";
}
.icon-email:before {
  content: "\e905";
}
.icon-eye:before {
  content: "\e906";
}
.icon-facebook:before {
  content: "\e909";
}
.icon-file:before {
  content: "\e90a";
}
.icon-gender:before {
  content: "\e90b";
}
.icon-instagram:before {
  content: "\e90c";
}
.icon-phone:before {
  content: "\e90d";
}
.icon-printer:before {
  content: "\e90f";
}
.icon-telegram:before {
  content: "\e910";
}
.icon-twitter:before {
  content: "\e911";
}
.icon-user:before {
  content: "\e912";
}
.icon-convert-light:before {
  content: "\e917";
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-chevron-double-left">Подключается путём добавления класса</div>
```